# copy table LSL implementation

Tags: embedded, infineon, automotive, tricore

example implementation for copytable for LSL and software.Need some help in understanding why copy table is always generated as 0 size in my map

example implementation for copytable for LSL and software.Need some help in understanding why copy table is always generated as 0 size in my map

```
        copytable
            (
                    align = 4,
                    dest = linear
                    ,
                    table
                    {
                            symbol = "_lc_ub_table_tc1";
                            space = :tc1:linear, :tc1:abs24, :tc1:abs18, :tc1:csa;
                    }
                    ,
                    table
                    {
                            symbol = "_lc_ub_table_tc2";
                            space = :tc2:linear, :tc2:abs24, :tc2:abs18, :tc2:csa;
                    }
                    ,
                    table
                    {
                            symbol = "_lc_ub_table_tc3";
                            space = :tc3:linear, :tc3:abs24, :tc3:abs18, :tc3:csa;
                    }
            );
            mpu_data_table;
```

this is part of my linker but memory allocated

would like to have a resolution on how we can allocate memory for a copy table

Comment: Please add the toolchain and version to your description.  It looks like it might be tasking tricore, but that's just an uninformed guess.

Comment: yes thats correct the tool chain used here is tasking and version is 6.2.

Comment: Add the information requested by editing the question, not by responding in a comment.  Although there are clues in the tags, some context in the question would help.